# Compare two strings without taking into account the position of the words that compose it

Tags: r, string

I know that, if

```
s1 <- "string"
s2 <- "String"
```

the comparison can be done as follows:

```
# Case-sensitive check
s1 == s2

# Case-insensitive check
tolower(s1) == tolower(s2)
```

What I have in mind, however, is a different kind of comparison:

```
s1 <- "John Smith"
s2 <- "Smith John"
```

If I apply previous code to this example, I obtain `FALSE` as result. But these two strings are formed by the same words, and I would like to have a comparison that gives, for this example, `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a function to split up the string by the space (`strsplit`), then `unlist`, `sort`, get the `unique` elements, `paste` them together again.

```
f1 <- function(x) toString(unique(sort(unlist(strsplit(tolower(x), " ")))))
f1(s1) == f1(s2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

NOTE: ASCII codes for upper case letters (65 to 90) and lower case letters (97 to 122) are represented by different numbers).  So, we need to make it to a standard case for comparison

Answer (score 2):

Using `utf8ToInt` :

```
check_string <- function(s1, s2) {
     sum(utf8ToInt(tolower(s1))) == sum(utf8ToInt(tolower(s2)))
}

check_string("string", "string")
#[1] TRUE
check_string("string", "String")
#[1] TRUE
check_string("John Smith", "Smith John")
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

These String are basically anagram of each other.
You can check for it by storing both string in map and compare both map.

dict(collection.Counter(S1) == dict(collection.Counter(S2)